# Populate multiple form fields from foreach statement

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to populate multiple form fields from a generated button in a `foreach` statement. I don't have a vast knowledge of `JS` so I don't know if I'm just not thinking of a certain function or not.

I have the following code and I'm able to get title to populate in the form but I have no clue where to start for populating content as well based of the same button. ex: one button will load a specific title and content value while another edit button will load another specific title and content value.

```
                //Announcement table select
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `announcements` ORDER BY `startDate` DESC"; //I want to see all existing announcements from database

                    $announcement = $dbConnect->query($sql);//execute query

$a = 0;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(title, content){
     document.getElementById('title').value = title.id;
     document.getElementById('content').value = document.getElementById(content).getAttribute('data-content');
}
</script>
<?php
foreach ($announcement as $row){ //Displays title, startDate, endDate from announcement table from database 
    $x[$a] = $row["title"];
    $y[$a] = $row["content"];

    echo "<h2 style=width:auto;padding:8px;margin-top:-30px;font-size:18px;><a style=text-decoration:none;color:#c4572f; >".$row["title"]."</a></h2><br>";
    echo "<p style=padding-top:10px;>".$row["content"]."</p><br>";
    echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$row["startDate"]."</p><br>";
    echo '<input id="'.$x[$a].'" type=button class=test onclick="changeText(this, '.$y[$a].');" value="Edit">';
    echo '<p id="'.$y[$a].'"  data-content="'.$row["content"].'">test</p>';
    echo "<h5 style=line-height:2px;margin-top:-15px;><p>_____________________________________</p></h5><br>";
}

                ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!--m4 ends here-->
                <div class="col m8 s8"> <!--m8 starts here-->
                    <div class="titleboxmargin grey" style="width:100%;">
                        <div class="bar yellow"></div>
                        <img class="boxicon" src="../images/announcementsicon.svg">
                        <h3 class="title">Announcements</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col yellow-light"> <!--Announcement Form Starts-->
                        <form action="includes/postAnnouncement.php" method="post">
                            <ul class="yellow-form">
                                <li class="textfield-container">
                                    <label for="text" class="textlabelblack">Title:</label>
                                    <input id="title" name= "title" type="text" placeholder="Title of My Announcement">
                                </li>
                                <li class="textfield-container">
                                    <label for="textarea" class="textlabelblack">Start Date:</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startDate">
                                </li>
                                <li class="textfield-container">
                                    <label for="textarea" class="textlabelblack">End Date:</label>
                                    <input type="date" id="endDate" name="endDate">
                                </li>
                                <li class="textfield-container">
                                    <label for="textarea" class="textlabelblack">Announcement:</label>
                                    <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="7"></textarea>
                                </li>
                                <li class="textfield-container">
                                    <div class="leftsidebutton">
                                        <input type="submit" class="button" style="width:auto; padding:5px; border:0;" name="register" value="Submit the form"/><!--Action: Attempts to Redirect to postAnnouncement.php-->
                                    </div>
                                </li>       
                            </ul>
                        </form>
```

The following code works

**Edit:**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeText(title, content){
               document.getElementById('content').value = document.getElementById(content).getAttribute('data-content');
               document.getElementById('title').value = document.getElementById(title).getAttribute('data-content');
       }
       </script>
       <?php
       foreach ($announcement as $row){ //Displays title, startDate, endDate from announcement table from database 
       $tile = $row["announcementID"] * 2;
       $cont = $row["announcementID"];


       echo "<h2 style=width:auto;padding:8px;margin-top:-30px;font-size:18px;><a style=text-decoration:none;color:#c4572f; >".$row["title"]."</a></h2><br>";
       echo "<p style=padding-top:10px;>".$row["content"]."</p><br>";
       echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$row["startDate"]."</p><br>";
       echo '<input id="'.$tile.'" data-content="'.$row["title"].'" type=button class=test onclick="changeText(id, '.$cont.');" value="Edit">';
       echo '<p id="'.$cont.'"  data-content="'.$row["content"].'">test</p>';
       echo "<h5 style=line-height:2px;margin-top:-15px;><p>_____________________________________</p></h5><br>";
      }

        ?>
```

Comment: Turns out its was a variable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a second parameter to your onclick handler:

```
$a = 0;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(elem, content){
     document.getElementById('title').value = elem.id;

     /* 
      * Here we get the value of the hidden content by the passed
      * in id and assign it to the value of the #content form element
      */
     document.getElementById('content').value = document.getElementById(content).value;
}
</script>
<?php
foreach ($announcement as $row){ //Displays title, startDate, endDate from announcement table from database 
    $x[$a] = $row["title"];
    $y[$a] = $row["content"];

    echo "<h2 style=width:auto;padding:8px;margin-top:-30px;font-size:18px;><a style=text-decoration:none;color:#c4572f; >".$row["title"]."</a></h2><br>";
    echo "<p style=padding-top:10px;>".$row["content"]."</p><br>";
    echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$row["startDate"]."</p><br>";
    echo '<input id="'.$x[$a].'" type=button class=test onclick="changeText(this, '.$y[$a].'); startDate('.$y[$a].'); " value="Edit">';
    echo '<p style="display:hidden;" id="'.$y[$a].'" ></p>';
    echo "<h5 style=line-height:2px;margin-top:-15px;><p>_____________________________________</p></h5><br>";
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
$a = 0;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(elem, contentID){
     var contentElem = document.getElementById(contentID);
     document.getElementById('title').value = elem.getAttribute('data-title');

     /* 
      * Get the value of the hidden content's data attribute by the passed
      * in id and assign it to the value of the #content form element
      */
     document.getElementById('content').value = contentElem.getAttribute('data-content');
}
</script>
<?php
// Let's get $index as well
foreach ($announcement as $index => $row){ //Displays title, startDate, endDate from announcement table from database 
    $x[$a] = $row["title"];
    $y[$a] = $row["content"];

    echo "<h2 style=width:auto;padding:8px;margin-top:-30px;font-size:18px;><a style=text-decoration:none;color:#c4572f; >".$row["title"]."</a></h2><br>";
    echo "<p style=padding-top:10px;>".$row["content"]."</p><br>";
    echo "<p style=font-size:10px;>Posted: ".$row["startDate"]."</p><br>";

    // Not sure if I'm escaping quotes correctly on this line:
    echo '<input id="title'.$index.'" data-title="'.$x[$a].'" type=button class=test onclick="changeText(this, \"content'.$index.'\"); startDate('.$y[$a].'); " value="Edit">';

    // Generate a unique id that we can reference
    // and add `data-content` attribute
    echo '<p style="display:hidden;" id="content'.$index.'" data-content="'.$y[$a].'"></p>';
    echo "<h5 style=line-height:2px;margin-top:-15px;><p>_____________________________________</p></h5><br>";
}
```

Comment: This is making progress but now on button click the title will some times fill in, it varies on the title. Also the text area fails to populate with the content. The script is storing the IDs correctly just not filling them in it appears.

Comment: Both title and content are strings, just an fyi.

Comment: I like the other answer's suggestion of using a JSON representation of the data. But, to try and correct my answer as it stands: It might be that you're adding 'content' (a string as you say), that may contain spaces or begin with a number and thus not be a valid ID. Instead of storing 'content' on the id of the hidden <p> you can use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Comment: My bad I found it. How would I use the getAttribute in the JS though?

Comment: Same result with the data-content. It will insert data "123" into the form but if its "test" it will fail to insert.

Comment: Hmm, it's too bad there isn't a _php_ fiddle. It's difficult for me to debug without trying it out in the context of the development environment.

Comment: I updated my original post to show the form as well. Hopefully this helps shed some light on things. Everything is storing correctly in the data-content, I can see the data value if I inspect the element.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted the working code in the edit on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your title and content values are, but I suspect they are *not* valid HTML element IDs. I think it would be better to avoid using the DOM as a data store and instead create a JSON representation of your announcement table in your script. My PHP is a little rusty, but it should be something similar to:

```
<script>
    var rows = <?php echo json_encode($announcement); ?>;
</script>
```

Hopefully this will produce something like the following:

```
var rows = [
    {
        "title": "Title One",
        "content": "Content One"
    },
    {
        "title": "Title Two",
        "content": "Content Two"
    }
];
```

This way, our changeText function need only accept a row index as parameter:

```
function changeText (index) {
    document.getElementById('title').value = rows[index].title;
    document.getElementById('content').value = rows[index].content;
}
```

All that is left is to pass the row index where we call changeText:

```
<?php foreach ($announcement as $index => $row) { ?>
    <!-- echo your HTML markup here. -->
    <button onclick="changeText(<?php echo $index; ?>);">Edit</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The "title" and "content" variables are DB values being returned in the foreach statement. Each for each has different "title and "content" values.

Comment: Yes. My answer is intended to reflect that.